# Application stops when clicked on Button

Tags: android, onclick, textview

Whenever i  click on Submit button, i get an error "Unfortunately, Application has stopped working." Please can you help me out.

Code-

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);   
            if(from == to)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid", 4000).show();

            }


            else
            {                                       
                  try {
                     s = getJson("URL");                        
                    JSONObject jObj;
                    jObj = new JSONObject(s);
                    String exResult = jObj.getJSONObject("query").getJSONObject("results").getJSONObject("rate").getString("Rate");
                    t.setText(exResult);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }                                                    
                }   

            }                               
    });
}
```

LogCat -

03-15 12:06:17.508: E/AndroidRuntime(877): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-15 12:06:17.508: E/AndroidRuntime(877): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
03-15 12:06:17.508: E/AndroidRuntime(877):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
03-15 12:06:17.508: E/AndroidRuntime(877):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
03-15 12:06:17.508: E/AndroidRuntime(877):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
03-15 12:06:17.508: E/AndroidRuntime(877):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
03-15 12:06:17.508: E/AndroidRuntime(877):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
03-15 12:06:17.508: E/AndroidRuntime(877):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
03-15 12:06:17.508: E/AndroidRuntime(877):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
03-15 12:06:17.508: E/AndroidRuntime(877):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
03-15 12:06:17.508: E/AndroidRuntime(877):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
03-15 12:06:17.508: E/AndroidRuntime(877):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
03-15 12:06:17.508: E/AndroidRuntime(877):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
03-15 12:06:17.508: E/AndroidRuntime(877):  at myandroid.myfirstmodule.sconverter.getJson(sconverter.java:163)
03-15 12:06:17.508: E/AndroidRuntime(877):  at myandroid.myfirstmodule.sconverter$1.onClick(sconverter.java:96)
03-15 12:06:17.508: E/AndroidRuntime(877):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
03-15 12:06:17.508: E/AndroidRuntime(877):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
03-15 12:06:17.508: E/AndroidRuntime(877):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-15 12:06:17.508: E/AndroidRuntime(877):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-15 12:06:17.508: E/AndroidRuntime(877):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-15 12:06:17.508: E/AndroidRuntime(877):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
03-15 12:06:17.508: E/AndroidRuntime(877):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-15 12:06:17.508: E/AndroidRuntime(877):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-15 12:06:17.508: E/AndroidRuntime(877):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
03-15 12:06:17.508: E/AndroidRuntime(877):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-15 12:06:17.508: E/AndroidRuntime(877):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: what is the problem when clicking the second button ?

Comment: I don't think placing submitfinal's onClick inside button b's onCLick is a right thing to do. Why do you need to do that?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve...?

Comment: Whenever i click on second button, i m automatically moved to the previous page.

Comment: ok..i m first fetching the data using yahoo api(when clicked first time..works well) and then manipulating that data to multiply it with text entered by the user in the textbox(by clicking on second button...automatically moved to previous page)

Comment: Hi, i've modified my code. Now, i m using only one submit button. The process should work in this way: (i) User will enter number in textbox1, say x. When clicked on submit, data will be fetched, say y and displayed on textview1. (ii) Then simultaneously, it should multiply x and y and display it on textview2. I wrote the code for it but again, i moved back to the previous page...please help.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you implement the onclickevent in the layout like this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click Here"
    android:onClick="btnClicked" />
```

Then define the method `btnClicked()`. I think that way you can use this onClickListener with a custom method. You can even use the same method for the button1 and inside of it determine which button has been called.

Comment: Hi, i've modified my code. Now, i m using only one submit button. The process should work in this way: (i) User will enter number in textbox1, say x. When clicked on submit, data will be fetched, say y and displayed on textview1. (ii) Then simultaneously, it should multiply x and y and display it on textview2. I wrote the code for it but again, i moved back to the previous page...please help.

Comment: Then add the new code here of edit your post. I don't think that you follow me and kdroider, because as I wrote you can modify the xml of the buttons and kdroider gave you a way to implement the method.

Comment: hi, may be you are right...but truly speaking, i didn't understand what exactly you mean? i m  bit new to android programming, so can u elaborate what exactly you said in the firs answer.

Comment: Implement the `android:onClick=` inside the layout of each button (you might want to use the same name. This name gives you the method to be called. The method is defined in your main_activity for example and there, use the code that kdroider provided you to determine which button was pressed. Aftert hat it's only you who knows what need to be done afterwards.

Comment: hi, did exactly the same u and kdroider said, but ending up with 3 errors on buttonClickListener saying "Illegal modifier for parameter buttonClickListener; only final is permitted" . What should i do next?

Comment: You're missing the `@Override` statement. Where exactly is this error? Is it in the definition of the function -if so, then why don't you put final there?

Comment: no friend, check it now, i've mentioned in the comments the actual error

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly is your goal in your code. But I don't think placing submitfinal's onClick inside button b's onCLick is a right thing to do. You need to handle them separately. If you want that in one onClickListener, you can do:

```
  int x, y, product; 
  public OnClickListener buttonClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()) {

            case <button b id>: 
                //fetch values of x and y
                                    x = Integer.parseInt(yourtextbox1.getText().toString());
                                    y = Integer.parseInt(yourtextbox2.getText().toString());
            break;
            case <button submit final id>: 
                //multiply x and y
                       product = x*y;
                    //display the product
                       yourtextbox3.setText(product);
            break;
            }
     };

 b.setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);
 submitFinal.setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);
```

EDIT:

On your current code, move the lines:

```
 t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);    
 displayfinal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
```

outside your onclick listener.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, i've modified my code. Now, i m using only one submit button. The process should work in this way: (i) User will enter number in textbox1, say x. When clicked on submit, data will be fetched, say y and displayed on textview1. (ii) Then simultaneously, it should multiply x and y and display it on textview2. I wrote the code for it but again, i moved back to the previous page...please help.

Comment: no brother, i m still 3 errors on the way u suggested me on buttonClickListener (object that we created) saying "Illegal modifier for parameter buttonClickListener; only final is permitted" and two errors on 2 buttonClickListener saying "buttonClickListener cannot be resolved to a variable". What should i do next?

Comment: hi friend, thanks so much for ur help...i was curious to solve it that i kept on asking my friends and finally found the solution. I m getting the output as expected but m sorry didn't try urs...anyways thanks once again for ur help

Comment: No Problem. If I was able to give the correct answer please accept my answer by clicking the check mark, otherwise, post your answer and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to move the listener of the second button from the else block. 
I think it is not a good practice to place a listener inside another listener

Comment: Hi, i've modified my code. Now, i m using only one submit button. The process should work in this way: (i) User will enter number in textbox1, say x. When clicked on submit, data will be fetched, say y and displayed on textview1. (ii) Then simultaneously, it should multiply x and y and display it on textview2. I wrote the code for it but again, i moved back to the previous page...please help.